# Добавить картинку от видео

Tags: java, android

Есть диалог, где по нажатию происходит обработка видео, а именно должна извлекаться картинка из видео.
Но выбивает ошибку, есть подозрения, что в методе showAddVideoDialog неправильно объявил метод uploadImageFromLink, потому как именно на моменте try catch и указывает, подскажите пожалуйста где я намудрил.

```
private void showAddVideoDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setTitle("Добавить видео");
    View viewInflated = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_layout_add_video, (ViewGroup) getView(), false);
    final EditText input = (EditText) viewInflated.findViewById(R.id.edt_videoUrl);
    builder.setView(viewInflated);

    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            try {
                uploadImageFromLink();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ОК", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Отмена", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}


String youtubeUrl="youtube.com";

private void uploadImageFromLink() throws IOException {
    Document videoPage = Jsoup.connect(youtubeUrl).get();

    Element videoIdMeta = videoPage.select("div[itemtype=http://schema.org/VideoObject] meta[itemprop=videoId]").first();
    if (videoIdMeta == null) {
    } else {
        String videoId = videoIdMeta.attr("content");

        String videoImageUrl = String.format("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/%s/hqdefault.jpg", videoId);
        Connection.Response response = null;
        try {
            response = Jsoup
                    .connect(videoImageUrl)
                    .ignoreContentType(true)
                    .execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(response.bodyAsBytes()));
    }
}
```

Comment: а непосредственно ошибку можно увидеть?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed URL: youtube.com но теперь я понимаю что ошибка в string... а что тогда туда прописать?(делал по примеру)

Comment: @Inkognito, у вас адрес не правильный. Как минимум нет протокола `http://`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ну если ссылки будет брать только с ютуба, то http:// youtube.com/ так или опять мимо?(

Comment: @Inkognito, вроде, всё верно

Comment: @ЮрийСПб сейчас пробую разные варианты, пробовал только протокол написать, ошибку не выбило, Toast сработал. С полным пинком не выходит, но вот в чем вопрос, есть же адрес и https и youtu.be линк. как такое обходить?